How to extract highest value based on the report_tye_code column
I would like to extract highest value row for each report_type_code. I have tried below sql query. On top of this, i need a condition to extract max value for each report_type_code.
SELECT gfrb.report_type_code,
       gfrb.report_folder,
       Max (gfrb.object_version_number) "MAX"
FROM   gl_frc_reports_b gfrb
WHERE  gfrb.report_path LIKE '%REP514%'
GROUP  BY gfrb.report_type_code,
          gfrb.report_folder 

Output



REPORT_TYPE_CODE
REPORT_FOLDER
MAX




Analysis
/shared/Custom/
10


Analysis
/shared/Custom/Transaction
2


Dashboard
/shared/Custom/Transaction
1


Dashboard
/shared/Custom/Transaction
4


Dashboard
/shared/Custom/Transaction
3



Expected Output



REPORT_TYPE_CODE
REPORT_FOLDER
MAX




Analysis
/shared/Custom/
10


Dashboard
/shared/Custom/Transaction
4



How can add additional condition to extract max value in above sql query?

Look into the row_number windows function.

What's the expected result if a REPORT_TYPE_CODE has two rows with the same max value?

Have a look: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group

You can use row_number window function to get each report_type_code's row having the highest object_version_number.
select report_type_code, report_folder, object_version_number
from
  (
  SELECT gfrb.report_type_code,
         gfrb.report_folder,
         gfrb.object_version_number,
         row_number() over (partition by gfrb.report_type_code
                            order by gfrb.object_version_number desc) rowno
  FROM   gl_frc_reports_b gfrb
) dt
where rowno = 1

If you want to include ties, use rank instead:
select report_type_code, report_folder, object_version_number
from
  (
  SELECT gfrb.report_type_code,
         gfrb.report_folder,
         gfrb.object_version_number,
         rank() over (partition by gfrb.report_type_code
                      order by gfrb.object_version_number desc) rnk
  FROM   gl_frc_reports_b gfrb
) dt
where rnk = 1

See the difference here: https://dbfiddle.uk/f2l4lKce
